# django static file loading adds a non-existent directory to the file path

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I have a Django project which has the following settings for loading static files:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'proj.apps.ProjConfig',
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "images/"),
]

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'login'
```

My `urls.py` is defined as:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from proj import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^login/$', auth_views.login, {'template_name': 'login.html'}, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', auth_views.logout, name='logout'),
] + staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

I have a file called `logo.png` which is copied to the satic directory when I run `python manage.py collectstatic` as expected.

My template for login (`login.html`) attempts to load this file as follows:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Login{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    {% load static %}
    <img src="{% static "logo.png" %}" alt="My image"/>

  <h2>Login</h2>
  <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Now the image is not loaded and the error comes with:

```
Not Found: /login/logo.png
```

I am not sure why it prepends the `/login/` directory to the path and I have been trying to figure this out for hours without luck!

I am in development mode (`Debug=True`) on a Windows machine. The path for the `logo.png` file is `proj_base_directory\\static\logo.png`

Comment: Are you in development or in production? And could you please put the path file for logo.png.

Comment: @Gil Added it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the solution to [serve static files during development](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development):

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    ....
] 

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

PROBLEM SOLVED:

Your `STATIC_URL` should be `STATIC_URL = '/static/'` in your settings.py

Comment: And your `STATIC_URL` should be `STATIC_URL = '/static/'´` in your settings.py

Comment: That was the issue! Can you write it as an answer, so that I can accept it!

Comment: Edited. Glad I helped ;)